# On error go to works in a module, but not in another

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

I do not understand why the following code works in a module...

```
On Error GoTo NO875

Workrange.Find("875 - COMPLEMENTO IT MANUAL").Select

On Error GoTo 0

'*****errorhandler****

NO875:

Workrange.Find("280 - MEJORA V. C. ABS.").Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.Select
Selection.insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeft
Workrange.Find("280 - MEJORA V. C. ABS.").Offset(0, 1).Value = "875 - COMPLEMENTO IT MANUAL"
```

But when I copy-paste the same code in another module, the following error message is displayed:

> Object variable or with block variable not set

Besides, in the first module, I can use the expression `xlFormatFromLeft`, but in the other module, I need to write `xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove`.

Any idea why this happens?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I place my bet that `Workrange` variable is not defined in the other module.

Comment: When using Find(), it's best to set the result to a `Range` variable, and then test that variable is not `Nothing` before trying to do anything with it.  that way you can mange "not found" without a run-time error.  You're also then not working with `Selection`, which it typically best avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Add `Option Explicit` to the top of each module.

This has a couple of benefits, you will be informed of undeclared variables, and the debugging messages will be a little more tailored and the line-in-error should be highlighted.

In this case, when you go to run the macro, the line with the undeclared variable will be highlighted. Noting here, that variables are declared within various scopes, and `Workrange` is probably declared at the Module level in one module, but not declared in the other.